# Обработка адресов с числами

Tags: регулярные-выражения, url

Есть адреса

```
http://cr36465.tmweb.ru/regions/amurskaya-obl_4292259/raychikhinsk_767/
```

как его привести к виду `http://cr36465.tmweb.ru/regions/amurskaya-obl/raychikhinsk/` то есть убирать **_число**? 
И какое правило для обработки писать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\d выбирает любую цифру.

все  /_\d+/ заменить на пустую строку - то, что вам надо

Comment: http://joxi.ru/E2peBeqHYwa9AY настроил вот так, как получить чтобы при переходе на адрес вида `http://cr36465.tmweb.ru/regions/amurskaya-obl_4292259/raychikhinsk_767/`открывался без чисел?

Comment: Зависит от используемого фреймворка/CMS. Общая рекомендация - редиректить с 301 на адрес без чисел, если числа в строке найдены, а на всех страницах сайта внутри числа убирать перед выводом в аттрибут ссылки